# Why is my CloudWatch count different than the AWS API Gateway error count?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I've created an alarm for API Gateway and modified the lambda function handler to something else so every curl request returns 5XX error when we try to call the Lambda function.

The alarm threshold is `5XX Error >= 1 for 1 data point within 1 minute`

It triggers the alarm but when I check metrics it shows a `Count` of 1 even though I used `curl` multiple times for multiple 5XX errors.

Why does the count show as 1 when I've triggered an error that should trigger the alarm 50 times?

I was expecting that it would show 50 counts.

Comment: It says "insufficient data" - how many times did you try invoking it? Read: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-alarm-insufficient-data-state/

Comment: I invoked it 10 to 20 times continually

Comment: The threshold you've set is **500 within 1 minute** - 10-20 isn't enough. Reduce the threshold or increase your number of requests by 30-50x

Comment: I changed the threshold to 1 but still not triggering. Updated screenshots

Comment: Now hit it 50 times and see what happens

Comment: It worked. Why do I need to trigger so many times and why it shows only 1 value when we got errors 50 times? I was expecting that it would show 50 counts

Comment: With the threshold set to 1, it doesn't get triggered if you send 1 failing request? It should be triggered as soon as you send 1 failing request.

Comment: It does trigger but the count shows that only 1 failure even if we try 50 times.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the **alarm** count, which is the count of how many times the alarm has been triggered based on the specific alarm period.

**You may have triggered the *error* 50 times, but your *alarm* is only triggered once per alarm period (within 1 minute).**

Regardless of if there are 2 requests or 500, you can only change the alarm state to `ALARM` once every 1 minute.

If you are looking for the API Gateway error count, monitor the metric separately.

**The alarm count is different to the metric count.**